# Is there a way in WoW Cataclysm to raise Steamwheedle Cartel reputation without harming Bloodsail Buccaneers?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there a way in World of Warcraft Cataclysm to raise your Steamwheedle Cartel reputation without harming your Bloodsail Buccaneers reputation?

For those who don't know, the *Free Knot!* quest in Dire Maul has been removed and *The Gordok Ogre Suit* in Dire Maul don't give goblins reputation anymore.

Comment: Th Steamwheedle Cartel contains 4 sub-groups: Gadgetzan, Booty-Bay, Everlook, and Ratchet. Was there one in particular you were looking to raise? You might get better answers that way.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: No I need to raise all of them but I would really like to keep my Bloodsail reputation intact too...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Fray Island Pirates will give you Booty Bay, Everlook and Gadgetzan rep at the same rate that the Bloodsail Buccaneer Pirates used to. I'm still trying to find another method of getting my Ratchet rep up since I'm 276 rep points short of exalted with them ><

Answer (score 4):

Look for Venture Company evacuees that give 5 rep, and an additional 2-3 for other goblin cities without lowering your Bloodsail rep; they can be found in Northrend in the Grizzly Hills sector (the southwestern-most part, where the ships near the light house PvP area are located). Specifically, the evacuees are on a ship in the "Venture Bay", in the middle of the 3 other ships; the other two are Allied and Horde PvP ships.  Make sure not to waste time with the Venture Company NPCs in the houses, as they no longer give rep (which is a shame as their respawn rate made it posible to get from Honored to Revered in under an hour). The respawn timer on the mobs on the ship is about 15 seconds long. Have fun and good luck1

Answer (score 2):

The [Venture Co. Workers](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=1096) (Geologists, etc.) clustered around the aptly named "Venture Co. Base Camp" in Northern Stranglethorn give 5 Booty Bay rep when killed, and 2 for the other three goblin towns.

This is in patch 4.0.3a, post-Cataclysm and post-Shattering. I'm not sure they'll get you all the way to Exalted, but they'll at least bring you up through Friendly, which is all you really needed, right?

Comment: I was going to say that he might need Exalted without hurting Bloodsail for the Insane in the Membrane achievement http://www.wowhead.com/achievement=2336 but it looks like you no longer have to be simultaneously Exalted with Steamwheedle and Honored with Bloodsail.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that another way to do it has also been removed - the low level pirates just south of Ratchet in the Barrens used to give Steamwheedle Cartel rep while not lowering Bloodsail Buccaneers, albeit at a slow and painful rate.  These pirates no longer exist, their location having been taken over by Alliance-friendly Northwatch Hold marines.

Comment: The Pirates are... gone??? Noooooooo!

Answer (score 1):

I thought the repeatable [Water Pouch Bounty](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=1878) quest gave you Steamwheedle Cartel reputation. However, I think I am wrong. You can check it out for yourself.

Also [here is a link](http://www.wowhead.com/faction=169) to quests for Steamwheedle Cartel.

Comment: As of Cataclysm, this repeatable quest is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

Wastewander'er kills in Tanaris give Ratchet, Booty Bay and Everlook reputation with no Bloodsail penalty.