# Is there a way in WoW Cataclysm to raise Bloodsail Buccaneers reputation without harming Steamwheedle Cartel?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

This is the opposite of my [previous question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11571/is-there-a-way-in-wow-cataclysm-to-raise-steamwheedle-cartel-reputation-without-h).

Is there a way in World of Warcraft Cataclysm to raise your Bloodsail Buccaneers reputation without harming your Steamwheedle Cartel reputation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today (Warlords), sadly no.

Answer (score 3):

This used to work some time ago but with all the changes in Cataclysm I don't know if it still does:
- get into a group or raid
- die in the middle of Booty Bay - you could fly up and dismount or just let the bruisers kill you
- stay dead and let the other people in your group kill the bruisers
- this used to give you rep with the Buccaneers without changing your rep with the Cartel
- the people doing the actual killing will still lose rep with the Cartel

I'd be surprised if this still works. Apart from that I'm not aware of any other way.

Comment: Don't know if it works, but sneaky. +1

Comment: This does not work anymore.